# Пиксель facebook ошибка при валюте UAH

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api

Использую скрипт для пиксель facebook

```js
    fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '999.00',  currency: 'UAH' });
```

Но консоль выдает ошибку

> fbevents.js:9 Facebook Pixel Error: Parameter "currency" is invalid for event "Purchase"

При использовании RUB или USD, ошибки нет. Как быть с UAH?

Comment: помог ответ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UAH не поддерживается вот весь лист [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/currencies)